# Thread.sleep() with synchronization in java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

when Thread.sleep(10000) is invoked current Thread will go to sleeping state.
If Thread.sleep(10000) is invoked in synchronization method whether other thread can execute in that period?

Answer (score 15):

If you do `Thread.sleep(10000)` within a synchronized method or block you **do not** release the lock. Hence if other Threads are waiting on that lock they won't be able to execute.

If you want to wait for a specified amount of time for a condition to happen and release the object lock you need to use `Object.wait(long)`

Answer (score 0):

```
private synchronized void deduct()
{
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ " Before Deduction "+balance);
    if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("First") && balance>=50)
    {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ " Have Sufficent balance will sleep now "+balance);
        try
        {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(100);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("ThreadInterrupted");
        }
        balance =  balance - 50;
    }
    else if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("Second") && balance>=100)
    {
        balance = balance - 100;
    }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ " After Deduction "+balance);
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ " "+balance);
}
```

I made this method as synchronized,I run two separate threads which are running concurrently & executing this method  producing unwanted results!!
If i comment the try catch block it will run fine,So is the synchronized block use is limited  till m not using these try catch block